# Run time error 1004, Application defined or object defined error

Tags: vbscript

I have written vbscript code to add chart in page 1 of excel for which the source is from other sheet of same excel which name is "CL.1.1"  but i am getting the above error can any one help what was wrong in my below code.

```
Sub DispvsTime(Shname)
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    noofsheets = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count
    If noofsheets > 0 Then
       ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Select
       ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Delete
    End If
    Sheets("Sheet1").Pictures.Visible = False
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(1000, 420, 50, 500).Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Shname").Range("G2:H2001")
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Displacement VS Time"
End Sub
```

here "shname" is name of the sheet where data is picked.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the line

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Shname").Range("G2:H2001")
```

be

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets(Shname).Range("G2:H2001")
```

since you want to use the variable Shname and not just a sheet named "Shname"

Hope this helps!

Comment: actually i used shname only when i debug the code it is giving the proper name oft he sheet. shname variable is replaced with actual value but still i am facing the issue